# Adjoint of norm map

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy

Let $G$ be a finite group acting trivially on a spectrum $X$. Then the norm map $X_{hG} \to X^{hG}$ may be thought of as a map $\Sigma^\infty_+ BG \wedge X \to F(\Sigma^\infty_+ BG , X)$. By adjointness, this corresponds to a map $\Sigma^\infty_+BG\wedge \Sigma^\infty_+ BG \wedge X \to X$. By naturality, it really suffices to consider the case where $X=S$ is the sphere spectrum, so we have a pairing $\Sigma^\infty_+ BG \wedge \Sigma^\infty_+ BG \to S$.

**Question:** What is this pairing?

All I can tell is that it restricts to the multiplication-by-$|G|$ map on $S$.

I'd be happy to understand the case $G = C_p$, $p$-locally.

Comment: I think it's a composite of the transfer $\Sigma^{\infty}_+(BG \wedge BG) \to \Sigma^{\infty}_+BG$ with the collapse map $\Sigma^\infty_+BG \to \mathbb{S}$. A possible reference is https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0011109.pdf.

Comment: Drew Heard is correct, and that transfer is associated to the diagonal inclusion of G into G x G.

Comment: @NicholasKuhn Thanks! What's a good way to see this?

Comment: @DrewHeard Thanks! There seems to be something like this in Section 8, but there's some mixing with $K(n)$-localization which is a bit confusing. Is it easy to see this?

Answer (score 4):

To elaborate the information in the comments:

Inside $G\times G$ you have the diagonal subgroup $\Delta$.  This gives a map 
$$ p\colon E(G\times G)/\Delta\to E(G\times G)/(G\times G) $$
This is a covering map, so it induces a transfer map $p^!$ of suspension spectra in the opposite direction.  We can identify $E(G\times G)/(G\times G)$ with $B(G\times G)=BG\times BG$, and $E(G\times G)/\Delta$ with $B\Delta\simeq BG$, so we have $p^!\colon BG_+\wedge BG_+\to BG_+$.  There is also a collapse map $BG_+\to S^0$, and by composing these, we get a stable map $BG_+\wedge BG_+\to S^0$.  This is the map that you are asking about.  A proof is contained in Theorem 8.3 of my paper "K(n)-local duality for finite groups and groupoids".  As you mention, that paper works in the $K(n)$-local context, but that does not really play any role in the proof of Theorem 8.3; it is easy to extract a proof of the unlocalised statement.  Nonetheless, the proof is more complicated than I feel it ought to be; it would be interesting to revisit the question using more modern foundations.

Comment: If you unwind Lurie’s “ambidexterity-style” construction of this map as in HA.6.1.6 then I think this ends up being the *definition*. (Not sure if that’s what you meant by “modern foundations”).

Comment: This construction was in various papers written around the time the Segal conjecture was being investigated: in the early 1980's. See for example, the appendix by Haynes Miller of [Ravenel, the Segal Conjecture for cyclic groups, Amer. J. Math. (1984)].

Comment: @NicholasKuhn Thanks! The connection to the Segal conjecture is very interesting to me.

Comment: @DylanWilson I'd be really interested to see this spelled out -- in Lurie's definition, one composes several maps, then takes several adjoints, making it complicated to work with. I finally decided to write it out as a string diagram, and I think it actually admits some simplifications. Anyway, one thing I'm not sure of is this -- how does the transfer of $BG \to B(G\times G)$ manifest itself here? I don't know what that means $\infty$-categorically...